# Build OpenCVSharp on my own occured lnk2001

Tags: c#, opencv, x86, gstreamer, lnk2001

I want to build opencvsharp, following [this](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp#how-to-customize-opencv-binaries-yourself) instruction.
x64 build was successfull but x84 was not.

[image]

Error Message

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___gst_message_type OpenCvSharpExtern   D:\OpenCV\opencvsharp\src\OpenCvSharpExtern\opencv_videoio460.lib(cap_gstreamer.obj)    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___gst_fraction_type    OpenCvSharpExtern   D:\OpenCV\opencvsharp\src\OpenCvSharpExtern\opencv_videoio460.lib(cap_gstreamer.obj)    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___gst_debug_min    OpenCvSharpExtern   D:\OpenCV\opencvsharp\src\OpenCvSharpExtern\opencv_videoio460.lib(cap_gstreamer.obj)    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___gst_caps_type    OpenCvSharpExtern   D:\OpenCV\opencvsharp\src\OpenCvSharpExtern\opencv_videoio460.lib(cap_gstreamer.obj)    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__gst_video_info_from_caps  OpenCvSharpExtern   D:\OpenCV\opencvsharp\src\OpenCvSharpExtern\opencv_videoio460.lib(cap_gstreamer.obj)    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__gst_version   OpenCvSharpExtern   D:\OpenCV\opencvsharp\src\OpenCvSharpExtern\opencv_videoio460.lib(cap_gstreamer.obj)    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__gst_uri_is_valid  OpenCvSharpExtern   D:\OpenCV\opencvsharp\src\OpenCvSharpExtern\opencv_videoio460.lib(cap_gstreamer.obj)    1
> .
> .
> .

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ - copy/paste text as text, especially error messages showing some of the symbols that were undefined in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know this message show that. I've built for x64 on same settings.I don't know why only for x86 can't be  built.

Comment: Your question only has a PNG image of the error messages, not text.